# .NET Core 2.0 LDAP/ AD Authentication using an SSL VPN tunnel

Tags: .net-core, ldap

I've developed an application in (.NET Core 2.0) and would like to communicate to customer’s AD service using an SSL VPN tunnel to authenticate user’s identity, following code works fine with local environment (looks like it works when code resides in the same domain).

```
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, userName, password);
        object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
    }
    catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException ex)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return false;
```

But the code doesn’t works when AD access thru an SSL VPN tunnel, getting an error message “The server is not operational.”, Any idea how to overcome this problem or any other alternatives?

Comment: Does the VPN allows the ldap request to pass through , check with the network admin to insure that the VPN is configured to allow LDAP traffic to pass through. Also check if you ping the Active Directory domain server.

Comment: Same question came in my mind, so tested the connectivity using trial LDAP Administrator tool and it works fine. So not sure what I’m missing.